# Error: Your project does not reference "MonoAndroid,Version=v5.0" framework

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

I have installed Xamarin on Visual Studio 2019
I started the first Android project

[TaregtFramework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmtTl.png)

I have sent the target framework in the picture
The project has nothing but two simple buttons
I get this error when I try to rebuild

[Error Prictre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1aO9.png)

Thank you for helping me find the problem

Fixing this error and why the MonoAndroid version file shows 0.0.0.0

Comment: Hey, avoid posting error messages as picture as it does not make it easy for others to help you. You can look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for other pointers. As for your problem, have you looked into your [sdk manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=windows) to see if you had the proper version installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can check whether the Nuget package supports the MonoAndroid version v5.0.

Second, from the Xamarin.Android 5.1, there is no mono.Android.Support.v4, so you need to change it to `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4`.

Third, you can check the [Setting up the Android SDK for Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=windows) to set the right version.